# how to append the data from file x to file y using cp command in linux?

Tags: linux, cp

I have file x and file y and I want to append all the contents of x into y without overwriting the file .

```
cp -r /source/y   /destination/x
```

I am searching different options of copy command for this but I am not getting the exact way of how to append the data with only copy command?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

The >> operator appends the output to the named file or creates the named file if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot do this with the copy command.  Other utilities can do what you want; for example most shells have a concatentation operator that would work:

cat /destination/x >> /source/y